# jQuery Ajax - Returning [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

```
$.get($(this).attr('id'), function(data){
var qp_post = $(data).filter('title');
alert(qp_post);
});
```

This fetches the content fine however the alert just says

```
[object Object]
```

When I do alert(data); it shows the HTML of the page perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is how jquery works. Are you looking for `alert( qp_post.html() );` ?